# Gradient Boost Decision Tree (GBDT) or Multiple Additive Regression Tree(MART): Calculating gradient/pseudo-response

Tags: machine-learning

I'm implementing MART from (http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~jhf/ftp/trebst.pdf) algorithm 5,
My algorithm "works" for say less data(3000 training data file, 22 features) and J=5,10,20 (# of leaf nodes) and T = 10, 20. It gives me good result (R-Precision is 0.30 to 0.5 for training) but when I try to run on some what large training data (70K records) it gives me runtime underflow error - which I think it should be - just don't know how workaround this problem?

Underflow err comes here, calculating gradient of cost (or pseudo-response):
[image]

here y_i are {1,-1} labels so if I just try: 2/exp(5000) its overflow in denominator!

Just wondering if I can "normalize" this or "threshold" this, but then I'm using this pseudo-response in calculating "label" (gamma in that pdf), and then those gamma to calculate model scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rrenaud is close, what I did is: if exp_arg > 16 or exp_arg < -16 make my exp_arg = 16(or -16) and it works! (For 1.2GB data and 700 features too!)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap that expression with an if.

```
exp_arg = 2 * y_i * F_m_minus_1
if (exp_arg > 700) {
  // assume exp() overflow, result of exp() ~= inf, 2 / inf = 0
  y_tilda_i = 0
else // standard calculation
```

I haven't implemented gradient boosting in particular, but I needed to do that trick in some neural network computation.